# LDAP Authentication failed: Invalid Credentials

Tags: ldap, gforge

In Gforge, when a new user tries to log in; the user is automatically registered by fetching data from LDAP. It works fine for other users but one particular user is not able to log in and gets the error LDAP Authentication failed: Invalid Credentials . I don't understand what could be the issue? Could you please help?
This is the search function I am using.

```
ldap_bind($ldap, $dn, $pw)
$dn = ldap_get_dn($ldap, $entry);
$entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap,$res);
$res=ldap_search($ldap, $sys_ldap_base,$sys_ldap_id_attribute . '=' . $id,
               array());
```

Comment: `ldap_search()` doesn't do authentication. It does searching. Question remains unclear.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you understand now?

Comment: If it works for some users but not for one specific user, then it's something to do with the LDAP configuration, or with the characters in that user's ID or pwd.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for some users but not for one specific user, then it's something to do with the LDAP configuration, or with the characters in that user's ID or pwd.

- Is the failing user in a different org/OU?  Do they have accent characters in their username or password?  These things can cause compatibility issues between GForge and the LDAP server.
- Does this user have a much longer user name than other users?  There is a GForge config setting called "usernameregex" that governs the complexity and length of allowed user names.  Even though LDAP logins result in automatic account creation, the validation of the user's unix name might fail due to the regex in place.  The error noted above could certainly be the catch-all message when this happens.

The default setting is **"^[a-z0-9_.-]{3,15}$"**.  You can change the upper length limit by changing the 15 to something else.  The unix_name field in the GForge database is TEXT, so it can be extremely long (1GB?).

In GForge 6.3.x and earlier, you can find that setting in /etc/gforge/gforge.conf.  Change the value and then update the system using:

`cd /opt/gforge/bin && php create_config_cache.php`

In GForge 6.4 and later, you can use the gf-config utility to set the value.  It will take effect right away:

`/opt/gforge/bin/gf-config set "usernameregex" "new regex value"`